# What does the italicised 'd' in this equation mean?

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, angle

not being a mathematician, I still need to understand this equation. I apologise in advance for the possibly trivial nature of this question.
Here is the equation:

[equation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAU6s.png)

I can't figure out what the *d* in this expression represents (all other terms are defined in the description of this equation)

Thank you in advance for your response

Theo

Comment: $d\theta$ tells you to intgrate with respect to $\theta$. In this case $d$ on its own is meaningless.

Comment: It's how integration is written: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Terminology_and_notation